# How to do a conditional cumulative shift function in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing many thousands of rows (text-based). I am trying to find a way to use the shift function to 'lookup' the previous X rows cumulatively, but am running into problems with NaNs.

Here is an example, where I have added three new columns; 'prev' looks up the previous row, 'prev2' looks up the previous two rows, and 'prev3' looks up the previous three rows.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'x':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['prev'] = df.x.shift()
df['prev2'] = df.x.shift(2)+df.x.shift(1)
df['prev3'] = df.x.shift(3)+df.x.shift(2)+df.x.shift(1)


----------------------------------------
   x   |   prev   |   prev2  |   prev3 
----------------------------------------
   a        NaN        NaN         NaN
   b        a          NaN         NaN
   c        b          ab          NaN
   d        c          bc          abc
   e        d          cd          bcd
   f        e          de          cde
   g        f          ef          d-e-f
   h        g          fg          efg
```

I am trying to find a way to address the NaNs in the three 'prev' columns. Specifically, I am looking to implement a conditional element that looks up the maximum number of previous rows if the original request results in a NaN. So, for instance in 'prev3', row C can only return a maximum of two previous letters A and B);  row B can only return one (A), and row A cannot return anything (in which case NaN is fine).

Ultimately, what I am looking to end up with is the following:

```
----------------------------------------
   x   |   prev   |   prev2  |   prev3 
----------------------------------------
   a        NaN        NaN         NaN
   b        a          a           a
   c        b          ab          ab
   d        c          bc          abc
   e        d          cd          bcd
   f        e          de          cde
   g        f          ef          d-e-f
   h        g          fg          efg
```

**Note:**  for this demo, 'd-e-f' is a proxy for the string 'def' to avoid any keyword related errors

Comment: can you `.fillna('')` with the empty string - your add should then give a similar desired result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `add` with `fill_value=''`

```
df['prev'] = df.x.shift()
df['prev2'] = df.x.shift(2).add(df.x.shift(1),fill_value='')
df['prev3'] = df.x.shift(3).add(df.x.shift(2),fill_value='').add(df.x.shift(1),fill_value='')
df
Out[7]: 
   x prev prev2 prev3
0  a  NaN   NaN   NaN
1  b    a     a     a
2  c    b    ab    ab
3  d    c    bc   abc
4  e    d    cd   bcd
5  f    e    de   cde
6  g    f    ef   def
7  h    g    fg   efg
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a super simple, but maybe surprising solution to this. You can use the `ffill` method with the argument `axis=1` to fill row-wise, resulting in your desired result except that the first row of the example will also be all a's, which should be easily solveable.

```py
In[1]:  df.ffill(axis=1)
Out[1]: 
   x prev prev2 prev3
0  a    a     a     a
1  b    a     a     a
2  c    b    ab    ab
3  d    c    bc   abc
4  e    d    cd   bcd
5  f    e    de   cde
6  g    f    ef   def
7  h    g    fg   efg
```